# Suppress Report Footer if Field is Null

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to suppress the report footer is a signature blob field is null using this in the section expert, details here:

[image: Crystal Reports Script]

However when I run the code checker it says the field name is not known.

Comment: have you checked the database connection?

Comment: Fields in Crystal tend to be referenced like {Table.Field}, are you missing the table part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the table name.  In this situation, that is the name of the procedure:

Try:

```
IsNull({spAppRptGetQuestionnaire;1.CustomerSignature1})
```